# Visual Studio 2017 Linux Console add more lines and see always the newest line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, console

Hei there,
I'm using VS2017 but I'm not happy with the Linux Conosle. I'm printing really fast and when I stop the program, I can't see what I have printed fist. It is already overwritten. How can I add lines? 
While printing the view is always at the oldest printouts, how can I change it, so I'm looking always to the newest print outs?

Cheers,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

to control your print flow you can use the command   less ,
https://www.gnu.org/software/less/

example : 
    curl http://somethingBig | less

Or, you can forward your output to a file :
    curl http://somethingBig > myFile